# Calling sql server stored procedure using python pymssql

Tags: python, sql-server, stored-procedures, pymssql, database-cursor

I am using pymssql for executing ms sql stored procedure from python. When I try to execute a stored procedure it seems not getting executed. The code gets completed without any error but upon verifying I can see the procedure was not really executed. What baffles me is that usual queries like select  and similar ones are working. What might be missing here? I have tried the below two ways. The stored procedure does not have any parameters or arguments.

```
cursor.execute("""exec procedurename""")
```

and

```
cursor.callproc('procedurename',())
```

EDIT: The procedure loads a table with some latest data. When I execute the proc from local, it loads the table with latest data but I can see the latest data is not being loaded when done from python using pymssql.

Comment: `callproc` is the preferred way as per the [Calling stored procedures](https://pymssql.readthedocs.io/en/stable/pymssql_examples.html#calling-stored-procedures) documentation.

Comment: What do you mean when you say the procedure was not really executed? Was it meant to insert a new record, update or delete an existing one? Please [Edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/70183465/edit) your question with more information about this.

Comment: Does the procedure return multiple result sets or messages?

Comment: The question is edited to add information on what the procedure is doing. The procedure does not return any result sets.

Comment: When calling it from Python are you calling `Connection.commit()` afterwards, or do you have the `Connection.autocommit` property set to `True`?

Comment: No, I am not using connection.commit() afterwards, I guess connection.autocommit is not set.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to AlwaysLearning to provide the crucial clue for fixing the issue, I have added connection.commit() after the procedure call and it started working!